# Find and remove multiple instances of words occurring after ='s and before comma

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of colors in column N of my spreadsheet and in each row/cell the list looks something along the lines of:

Medium Blue=Blue,Light Blue=Blue,Medium Green=Green,Medium Orange=Orange,Medium Orange=Burnt Orange,Medium Gray=Stainless,Dark Red=Burnt Orange

I'm trying to look through each cell, find all instances of ='s and compare the string after ='s until the next comma (ex: it would look at "=ESP,") to see if this value occurs multiple times throughout the same cell (it's ok if the same values are in different cells). If the value occurs multiple times within the same cell I need to remove the string after the ='s and replace it with what's before the ='s. After all that is done, I also need to make sure that there are no two like values ("Light Blue & Medium Blue=Light Blue" are considered the same). So, the above String should look like this when correct (Leaving the trailing comma):

Medium Blue=Blue,Light Blue=Light Blue,Medium Green=Green,Medium Orange=Orange,Medium Orange=Burnt Orange,Medium Gray=Stainless,Dark Red=Dark Red

```
 'This is to figure out how many times to loop through a cell (Number of occurances
 'of "=" in a given cell
 'LEN(N2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(N2,"=",""))
Dim endRange As Integer
Dim equalCount As Integer

endRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through each row in the column
For N = 2 To endRange

'Skip over a row if there is nothing in the cell
If ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value <> "" Then

    'Counts how many ='s there are in each cell
    equalCount = Len(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value) - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, "=", ""))

    'Loops through a cell once for every ='s
    For c = 1 To equalCount
        Dim commaPos As Integer
        Dim equalPos As Integer

        'Find the next comma & that's immediately after the particular ='s
        commaPos = FindN(",", ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, (c))
        equalPos = FindN("=", ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, (c))

        'Search the cell to see how many instances of the value between the ='s and ,
        If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(InStr(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, _
        Mid(Right(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, commaPos), Left(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, equalPos), _
        equalPos - commaPos)), ">1")) Then

        MsgBox ("Found a Duplicate!")
        End If

    Next c
End If

    Next N
    End Sub
```

I keep getting a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" Error. Also, I'm pretty sure if this did work it still wouldn't catch values at the end of the string since there is not another comma to find after the last ='s.

*edit*

My function

```
 Function FindN(sFindWhat As String, _
 sInputString As String, N As Integer) As Integer
 Dim J As Integer
 Application.Volatile
 FindN = 0
 For J = 1 To N
     FindN = InStr(FindN + 1, sInputString, sFindWhat)
     If FindN = 0 Then Exit For
 Next
 End Function
```

Comment: Where do you get the error, what line?

Comment: 'If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(InStr(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, _
        Mid(Right(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, commaPos), Left(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & N).Value, equalPos), _
        equalPos - commaPos)), ">1")) Then'      It seems to point towards the CountIf in that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different approach using `Split()`

**EDIT**: added detecting single values vs =-separated pairs

```
Function FixItUp(v)
    Dim arr, e, b, a, rv, sep, arrV
    Dim ex As String

    arr = Split(v, ",")
    'loop over each pair of values
    For Each e In arr
        arrV = Split(e, "=")
        b = Trim(arrV(0))

        If UBound(arrV)>0 Then
            'is a =-separated pair of values...
            a = Trim(arrV(1))
            'seen the "after" before?
            If InStr(ex, Chr(0) & a & Chr(0)) > 0 Then
                a = b 'seen already, assign "after" = "before"
            Else
                ex = ex & Chr(0) & a & Chr(0)
            End If
            rv = rv & sep & b & "=" & a
        Else
            'deal with the single "b" value here....
        End If

        sep = "," 'separator is now a comma...
    Next e

    FixItUp = rv
End Function
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. You are the best! I can't believe I spent so much time thinking about such a complex method. I feel like such a novice now. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, there's just one issue. It appears to give a "#VALUE!" error when looking at a string longer than 160 characters. Any idea why?

Comment: Try calling it from a Sub instead of from a workbook cell - that should highlight the problem

Comment: I tried calling it from a sub like so:Dim endRange As Integer
endRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

For cCell = 2 To 3
If ActiveSheet.Range("N" & cCell).Value <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("N" & cCell).Value = FixItUp(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & cCell).Value)
End If
Next cCell

Comment: When I run that I get a Runtime Error 9 subscript out of range and it seems to point towards this line in the function : a = Trim(Split(e, "=")(1)). Here's the text I was trying to run it on if that makes a difference: Clear,Medium Gray=Gray,Light Gray=Gray,Other=ESP,Medium Yellow=Yellow Lens,Other=ESPs,Other=ESP,Medium Orange=Yellow Lens

Comment: And it also seems that the code is giving me a #VALUE error for any length I try it on (from within a worksheet)

Comment: Values on either side of the = can't contain commas or it's impossible to split the pairs of values up...  So it won't work with the value you show.

Comment: I don't follow. My original data set that I shared with you has commas on each side and it worked yesterday.

Comment: It didn't (I assumed) have commas *within any of the values being compared*, only separating the pairs of values.  If commas can be in *either* location then there's no obvious way to split things up...  Is "Clear,Medium Gray" a single value ?

Comment: No,"Clear,Medium Gray" are two separate values

Comment: But they appear at the beginning of the string?  How should that be treated ?

Comment: As two separate strings. Each value that is between commas is one value/string. You were helping with having each of those string separated again and the values after the ='s and before the following comma and seeing if it has more than one instance and if so you'd rename it the color name that was before the =. For some reason it worked yesterday, but not today on the same string

Comment: So it should ignore the "Clear" and just look at "Medium Gray=Gray" when comparing values ?  Should the output string include the "Clear" ?

Comment: The clear should stay and it should look at both "Clear" and "Medium Gray=Gray" separately as different values. Clear should be checked to see if there are any more Clear (even if the other is an "=Clear,") and if it finds more than one it should only leave one. I have a function that removes duplicates between two commas (Say "Medium Blue=Blue,Medium Blue=Blue,Yellow") it would remove "Medium Blue=Blue." So as long as you can take care of checking values after ='s against all other values and assigning the value in front of the ='s if there is a duplicate value then that'll work

Comment: So there can be comma-separated "pairs" of values on either side of `=` ?  So "A,B=C,D,E=F" is a valid input?  How would you parse that?

Comment: Yes, but they wouldn't be considered the pairs. It would be Value 1='A', Value 2='B=C', Value 3='D', Value 4='E=F'. Keep in mind that Values 'C' and 'F' are still considered values alone and should be checked against all letters as well (so, 'C' needs to be compared to 'A' & 'F' and if it matches either one then 'C' should just take on the name of 'B' by default.)

Comment: See my edit - should give you a start on getting it to handle the other inputs

Comment: The updated code does the trick for the values with ='s but completely eliminates those that are single/simple values Blue,Red,Green,etc. How do I handle that so they are just left alone?

Comment: Put the appropriate code where is says "deal with the single "b" value here...."  My edit was intended just as a starting point for you to complete.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just now saw the comments. I was at work when I first got your responses. I have been able to successfully keep the single b values by insert "rv = rv & sep & b." The only problem I have left is I'm not sure how to go about a situation like when there are two values such as "Light Yellow=Gold" & "Gold". Any advice with how to handle that? In a case like that I'd like to drop the "=Gold" on the one value. Sorry I'm bugging you so much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of the effort and help from @Tim Williams I've been able to build off of what he gave me and finally constructed a function that suits my needs. I'll post this here in case someone else needs it

```
Function CleanColor(v)
Dim arr, e, b, a, rv, sep, arrV
Dim ex As String

arr = Split(v, ",")
'loop over each pair of values
For Each e In arr
    'Split up values further by using equals as delimiter
    arrV = Split(e, "=")
    'Trimming space off alias if there is a space and setting alias to b
    b = Trim(arrV(0))
    'Looking at array bounds and if there more than 1 slot (slot 0) then we have an =-separated pair
    If UBound(arrV) > 0 Then
        'is a =-separated pair of values...
        a = Trim(arrV(1))
        'count how many times the "after" appears in the entire v string
        Dim count As Integer
        count = (Len(v) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(v, Chr(61) & a, ""))) / Len(Chr(61) & a)
        'seen the "after" before?
        If InStr(ex, Chr(0) & a & Chr(0)) > 0 Or count > 1 Then
            If b <> "Other" Then
                a = b 'seen already, assign "after" = "before"
            Else
                GoTo endFor
            End If
        Else
            ex = ex & Chr(0) & a & Chr(0)
        End If
        rv = rv & sep & b & "=" & a
    Else
        'deal with the single "b" value here....
        a = e
        'seen the single value before?
        If InStr(ex, Chr(0) & a & Chr(0)) > 0 Then
            ex = ex 'seen already, don't add to string
        Else
            ex = ex & Chr(0) & a & Chr(0)
            rv = rv & sep & b
        End If
        'rv = rv & sep & b

    End If

    sep = "," 'separator is now a comma...
endFor: Next e

CleanColor = rv
End Function
```

Thank you again Tim Williams for all your help!